# Differentiate the conditional CDF to get the conditional PDF

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, definition

Let $X$ and $Y$ be 2 continuous random variables.

Then, the conditional PDF of $X$ given $Y$ is

$f(x | y) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f(y)}$.

1) What is the definition of the conditional CDF of $X$ given $Y$?

2) How do I differentiate the conditional CDF so that I get the conditional PDF?  I think that I should differentiate with respect to $X$, but then I would not get the marginal PDF of $Y$ in the denominator of the conditional PDF.

Comment: That's a bizarre definition of conditional CDF, because you seem to be conditioning on $Y\leq y$, as opposed to $Y=y$. The latter would correctly give you the PDF density after differentiating in $x$. Could you double check your definition?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Alex.  Allow me to specify that X and Y are both continuous, so P(Y = y) = 0.  I got the definition of the conditional CDF from http://www.colorado.edu/economics/morey/7818/jointdensity/NotesonConditionalCDFs/ConditionalCDF_Edward.pdf

Comment: Your reference is clear: $F(x|y)$ is the CDF "of a random variable $X$ given that we know that the random variable $Y$ is less than a given value" (p. 3).  The formula you give for $f$ is, on the other hand, conditional on $Y$ being *exactly equal* to $y$.  You're writing about two different things.  So, it seems, is your reference: starting at p. 11, it suddenly re-interprets $F_{X|Y}(x,y)$ as the CDF conditional on $Y=y$; then it assumes it is the CDF conditional on $Y\le y$; and at that point it's completely off the rails and getting wrong answers. Find another resource.

Comment: Thanks whuber. I just want to learn how to differentiate a conditional CDF of 2 continuous random variables to get the conditional PDF. Please forgive me for not knowing the proper way to write this and for finding a bad reference. Could you please show me how to do it properly?

Comment: First we have to make the definitions clear.  Are you sure the ones you have quoted are the ones you want to relate to each other?  If so, there's no way to get from one to the other without additional information.

Comment: I don't know what the right definitions should be - I'm really lost.  Could you please educate me on what the right definitions are and how to differentiate the CDF? I know that I am not making my question 100% clear, but I can't find a definitive definition of the conditional CDF on the web. I think that my question is 80% clear, and I hope that it's good enough for you to clarify and elaborate further.

Comment: I have removed the definition of the conditional CDF in my original post and now ask for it as a question.

Comment: Is there a reason no one has asked for the self-study tag to be added?

Comment: Analyst1 - This is not a homework question.  I am really curious about this and cannot find any reliable source on the Internet to answer my question.

Comment: Obviously, $$F_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=P(X\leqslant x\mid Y=y)=\frac1{f(y)}\int_{-\infty}^xf(z,y)dz$$

Comment: Did - If Y is a continuous variable, then does it make sense to condition on Y = y?  Isn't P(Y = y) = 0?

Comment: the density value $f(y)$ is _not_ the probability that $Y=y$, which is indeed zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$, $Y$ be two RV's and we do not assume that they are independent. Now we are asking questions about the distribution of $X$ given $Y$.

As you stated, the conditional PDF of $X$ given $Y$ is
$$f\left(X=x|Y=y\right)=\frac{f\left(X=x,Y=y\right)}{f\left(Y=y\right)}$$

For the ease of understanding, we can define a new continuous variable $Z_{y}$ that is equal in distribution to $X$ for any given $Y=y$, that is:

$$P\left(Z_{y}<z\right)=P\left(X<z|Y=y\right)\,\forall\,z,y$$

and thus we get:

$$f\left(Z_{y}=z\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}P\left(Z_{y}<z\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}P\left(X<z|Y=y\right)=f\left(X=z|Y=y\right)\,\forall\,z,y$$

Note that since we are *conditioning* on $Y$, when observing $Z_{y}$ we can relate to $y$ as a constant. Now we can answer your questions quite easily using our previous knowledge in univariate probability:

$$P\left(X<x|Y=y\right)=P\left(Z_{y}<x\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(Z_{y}=u\right)du=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(X=u|Y=y\right)du=\frac{1}{f\left(Y=y\right)}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(X=u,Y=y\right)du$$

And the other way around:

$$f\left(X=x|Y=y\right)=f\left(Z_{y}=x\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}P\left(Z_{y}<x\right)\\=\frac{1}{f\left(Y=y\right)}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{-\infty}^{x}f\left(X=u,Y=y\right)du=\frac{f\left(X=x,Y=y\right)}{f\left(Y=y\right)}$$

The major point I'm trying to make here is that for an RV $X$ and for every given $Y=y$ we can define a new RV $Z_{y}\overset{d}{=}\left\{ X|Y=y\right\}$  which we can relate to as a univariate RV with $y$ as a parameter. Everything else will be the same as we learned in basic probability.